# Reconstructing plane graphs from degree- and face-sequences

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry, polyhedra, planar-graphs

Let $G$ be a plane $3$-connected graph; so it partitions the plane
into regions bounded by faces.
Let $\mathrm{deg}_v$ be the sequence of vertex degrees of $G$,
and $\mathrm{deg}_f$ be the sequence of the number of edges bounding
each face, or, equivalently, the vertex degrees in the dual of $G$.
Not always do $\mathrm{deg}_v$ and $\mathrm{deg}_f$ uniquely determine $G$.
Here is a $2$-connected triangulated example, but similar $3$-connected examples
can be constructed.
(Notation: $5^2 4^3 3^4 2^2 = 5,5,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,2,2)$.

---

[image: DegSeqs]

          

<sup>Nonisomorphic $2$-connected graphs with the same $\mathrm{deg}_v$ and $\mathrm{deg}_f$ sequences.</sup>

---

> ***Q1***. I am seeking an algorithm that will take as input 
>   $\mathrm{deg}_v$ and $\mathrm{deg}_f$ sequences,
>   and output a plane graph $G$ that realizes these sequences
>   (if they are compatible sequences).

Algorithms exist for realizing $\mathrm{deg}_v$ (see, e.g., 
[Mathworld Graphic Sequences](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphicSequence.html)),
but here I have (a) planarity, and (b) the dual degree sequence.

> ***Q2***. I have a sense that $\mathrm{deg}_v$ and $\mathrm{deg}_f$ "usually"
>   determine a unique plane $G$ (if they are mutually consistent).
>   Is this intuition correct? Can you suggest a precise formulation of the question?

Comment: Regarding Q2, any two fullerenes on the same number vertices have the same degree and face-degree sequences.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil: Could you explain a bit why, for those not fullerene aficionados.

Comment: O’Rourke:  A fullerene is a cubic planar graph with exactly 12 face 5-gons ans the remaining faces 6-gons. There are lots of them, e.g., 1812 on 60 vertices according Brinkmann and Dress https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196677496908068